# Java type specification in ArrayList instance

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, arraylist

In using JDK 1.8 in Eclipse IDE, there is no raw type warning for the following line:

1) `ArrayList<Double> d1 = new ArrayList<>();`

But there is a compiler warning for:

2) `ArrayList<Double> d2 = new ArrayList();`

Syntactically, the only difference is the angle brackets "<>". But in neither case is the type actually specified. If the angle brackets are left empty, is the type `Double` inferred?

Comment: Yes, as long as the compiler can infer it from the context, you can omit the type parameter.

Comment: Just FYI, the empty angle brackets like `<>` in java are called the *diamond operator*

Comment: To answer the obvious question; "why does it behave like that?" Because raw types are a necessary evil to support backwards compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - yes.

Empty angle-brackets (`<>`) allow the compiler to infer the generic type. As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) states:

> You can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (<>) as long as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context. This pair of angle brackets is informally called the diamond.

Which, to quote the documentation again, is quite different from using the raw type:

> Note that to take advantage of type inference during generic class instantiation, you must use the diamond.

Answer (score 0):

```
    new ArrayList()
```

This creates a raw type. The raw type can be assigned to a generic `ArrayList<Whatever>` with an *unchecked* warning, because it is indeed unsafe for the type system.

```
    new ArrayList<>()
```

This creates a generic type; the type argument is inferred from context.